# How to build app for android 2.3 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am working on a project: creating an app for an old android device with Android Studio. But the problem is targetting the correct API Level (9) and appcompat from gradle.

I did some modifications like: inserting in AndroidManifest.xml the following:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
```

removed in gradle.xml from dependencies :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
```

I set the *Compile Sdk Version* to *API 9: Android 2.3 (Gingerbread)* and *Min Sdk Version* to *API 9: Android 2.3 (Gingerbread)*

I also removed from the main class the inheritance from AppCompat and changed it to Activity.

But even with all these tweaks it still won't build.What else can I do?

Comment: If nothing else, you need to drop the version of `support-v4` to `25.4.0`, as newer versions than that do not support API Level 9. You might also need to set your `targetSdkVersion` to 25 -- if you do, that will prevent you from shipping this app on the Play Store starting later this year.

Comment: Thanks for advice.But how do I drop support-v4 to 25.4.0? And I forgot to mention,but I don't want to post it at all in Play Store.It is just for internal use.

Comment: "But how do I drop support-v4 to 25.4.0?" -- replace `27.1.1` with `25.4.0`. So, instead of `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'`, you have `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'`.

Comment: So it is supposed to look like this:  'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0' ?

Comment: So after changing the support I had to replace the imports which look like this now:
import android.support.v4.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

public class mainWindow extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_window);
    }
}
But R is not recognized.

Comment: Perhaps your activity is not in the same Java package as `R`. Perhaps you have a build error, such as a problem with resources, that is preventing Android Studio from generating `R`. Perhaps you just need to force Android Studio to build the app (Build > Make 'app' from the main menu) to get it to create `R` for you.

Comment: The 1st error is: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (aka com.horizon.app.app:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) not found.

Comment: So that means AppCompat is not accesible.

Comment: But there is not other theme available where the error comes from:

Comment: <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>